# $SGE_TASK_ID not getting set with qsub array grid job

Tags: arrays, zsh, hpc, qsub, sungridengine

With a very simple `zsh` script:

```
#!/bin/zsh

nums=(1 2 3)
num=$nums[$SGE_TASK_ID]
```

`$SGE_TASK_ID` is the sun-grid engine task id. I'm using qsub to submit an array of jobs.

I am following what is advised in the qsub manpage (http://www.clusterresources.com/torquedocs/commands/qsub.shtml#t) and submitting my array job as

```
#script name: job_script.sh
qsub job_script.sh -t 1-3
```

$SGE_TASK_ID is not being set for this array job... does anyone have any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are using `bash`? I can't trigger that error in `bash`, and I think Sun uses a different shell as its `/bin/sh`. In any case, the given answers should work.

Comment: whoops, I'm sorry, I'm on zsh. I didn't think that would matter, because I'm sure I could have done the same commands in the bash environment, which is the default environment settings..

Comment: My personal opinion: go ahead and edit this question, replacing the old question. None of the current answers are relevant to the real question of why `SGE_TASK_ID` isn't set.

Comment: The manpage that you site is for Torque, not SGE.  They both have a qsub command, but they are rather different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks everyone for the answers. I found a solution that works:

Depending on how the cluster is set up, the Sun Grid Engine might be configured to use another variable name for array ids.. This was the case for me. I found out the variable to use by doing the following:

> // job_script.sh

```
#!/bin/zsh
env >> ~/job_env
set >> ~/job_env
```

This dumps all environment variables set by the script into a file called job_env. Just simply look in the file and look for a variable array ID that is incremented for each job. Should not be that hard to find.

Remember to submit the job_script.sh with qsub as follows:

```
qsub -t 1-3 job_script.sh
```

In my case, the ID that was set was $PBS_ARRAYID. I don't think that's the default so $SGE_TASK_ID should work for standard SGE setups on clusters.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try submitting the job like this:

```
qsub -t 1-3 job_script.sh
```

and see what happens.

Observe:

```
qsub -sync y job_script.sh -t 1-3
Your job 74578 ("job_script.sh") has been submitted
Job 74578 exited with exit code 0.
```

vs.

```
qsub -sync y -t 1-3 job_script.sh
Your job-array 74579.1-3:1 ("job_script.sh") has been submitted
Job 74579.3 exited with exit code 0.
Job 74579.1 exited with exit code 0.
Job 74579.2 exited with exit code 0.
```

Note, torque (the referenced man page in your question) is a little different from SGE.  My SGE man page definitely suggests putting all options before the command.  Also, SGE doesn't like that "%" syntax for limiting the max number of simultaneous jobs, but mine at least lets me say -tc NNN to specify the limit (not mentioned in the man page, but in qsub -help).

Answer (score 1):

To access to a position in your array, you have to do it like this: `${the_array[$the_position]}`.

So in your case,

```
num=${nums[$SGE_TASK_ID]}
```

Test:

```
$ nums=(1 2 3)
$ SGE_TASK_ID=1
$ echo ${nums[$SGE_TASK_ID]}
2
```

note that the first position is the 0th.

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround the array variable with curly braces:

```
SGE_TASK_ID=2
nums=(1 2 3)
num=${nums[$SGE_TASK_ID]}
echo "num: $num"
# prints "num: 3"
```

The Linux Documentation Project has the [best shell scripting docs](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html)

Comment: Thanks! I tried all this and it wasn't working. I've realised I made a mistake in identifying the error, and have updated the problem I'm having.