# Batch job on lustre is not working: awk: cmd. line:1 "unexpected newline or end of string"

Tags: python, bash, awk, sungridengine

I have recently started running Python batch jobs on a Lustre system.

I have recently made changes to the shell script, resulting in the error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: NR==
awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

The script is as follows:

```
#$ -cwd


# Define parallel environment for N cores
#$ -pe openmp 4



# Validation level (e = reject on all problems)
#$ -w e

# Merge stdout and stderr streams: yes/no
#$ -j yes

#name of job (human-friendly)
#$ -N experiment

# array job parameters below:
# which job IDs in the array to run, eg 1-5 or 3
#$ -t 1
# how many jobs of the array to run at a time
#$ -tc 15


MYFILE=all_experiment_parameters.txt.$RANDOM
python Get_Parameter_Settings.py > $MYFILE
SEED=$(awk "NR==$SGE_TASK_ID" $MYFILE)
echo $SEED

python RunExperiment.py $SEED
```

This is similar to the syntax in the example given in section 'Pulling data from the ith line of a file' here: http://wiki.gridengine.info/wiki/index.php/Simple-Job-Array-Howto.

Could someone advise on the meaning of the error message (I don't understand why it is warning of 'newline or end of string', when pointing at the middle of my code), and how to fix this? I'm sure it is a trivial change I have made by mistake, as it was working earlier.

Comment: How is `$SGE_TASK_ID` supposed to be set?

Comment: SGE sets a variable ('SGE_TASK_ID') in the environment of the executing task which can be used within the job script to identify the correct input data to be used by the job task (from http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/bioinfsupport/help/cluster_usage/submitting_array_jobs) ... so I thought it was automatically set by Sun Grid Engines..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realised why SGE_TASK_ID wasn't getting set. I was running the shell script using

```
./shell.sh
```

instead of submitting it to the queue with

```
qsub shell.sh
```

So a total beginner's mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: NR==
awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

because your environment variable `SGE_TASK_ID` isn't set in this line of your script:

```
SEED=$(awk "NR==$SGE_TASK_ID" $MYFILE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I thought this variable was automatically set, as mentioned in my comment above?

Comment: @user3140106 The error message is showing you it isn't set.

Comment: I found another stack overflow post asking a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483977/sge-task-id-not-getting-It-set-with-qsub-array-grid-job) It seems that I need to find the variable array ID that is incremented for each job, and set this to $SGE_TASK_ID. Do you know how I can find this?

Comment: Its better to set the variable outside the `awk` code: `SEED=$(awk -v var="$SGE_TASK_ID" 'NR==var' $MYFILE)`